# Getting the element that occupies the top of the parent element

Tags: javascript, html

Given a parent `div` that can scroll vertically and has possibly nested elements within it, how can I get the (innermost) element that currently occupies the top end of the parent div?

For example, suppose I have the parent div as the light blue area in the diagram below, and it has objects in it, that are colored blue or red, some parts of them being outside of the parent div (which should actually be hidden). I want to get the object colored in red.

[image: nesting]

I can probably do this by comparing the `offsetTop` of the child elements with that of the parent element, and recursively go inside.

Comment: I was expecting you to share some sample code and efforts put to achieve the solution..

Comment: as asked by Rayon Dabre, do add code and if possible do add image for expected solution.

Comment: `that currently occupies the top end of the parent div` Difficult to comprehend without relevant markup.

Comment: please show us what you have tried before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the code snippet below to see one solution. Scroll the window to move the divs relative to the window, then click the button to see the id of the innermost div that is at the top of the window. This solution assumes all divs are "normally" nested, i.e. there is no re-arrangement of div vertical placement by fancy css work, no fixed positions, etc.

There are two versions below: the first uses jQuery, the second does not.

```js
$("button#check").click(function() {
  var topElem = $("body")[0];                          // start at the outermost, i.e. the body
  var checkChildDivs = function() {                    // define the recursive checking function
    var children = $(topElem).children("div").not("div#info"); // get all child divs
    if (children.length > 0) {                         // if there are any child divs
      $(children).each(function(index, elem) {         // check each of them
        var posns = getPosns($(elem));                 // get their top and bottom posns
                                                       //   relative to the top of the screen
        if ((posns.top <= 0) && (posns.bottom >= 0)) { // if the div overlaps the screen top
          topElem = elem;                              // make this the new innermost div
          checkChildDivs();                            // check any deeper child divs
          return false;                                // no need to check any lower sibling divs
        }
      });
    }
  };
  checkChildDivs();                                    // initiate the checking recursion
  $("div#info").text($(topElem).attr("id") || "none, i.e. body"); // report the innermost top div id
});

function getPosns($elem) {
  var top = $elem.offset().top;    // get the top of the div relative to the document
  var hgt = $elem.outerHeight();   // get the height of the element
  var wst = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the height of window hidden above the top of the screen
  return {                         // return the top and bottom distances of the element
    top: (top - wst),              // relative to the top of the screen
    bottom: (top - wst + hgt)
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
div {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: magenta;
}
div > div {
  background-color: red;
}
div > div > div {
  background-color: orange;
}
div >div > div > div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
button#check {
  position: fixed;
  height: 2em;
}
div#info {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 3em;
  left: -0.2em;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 15em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="check">Determine Id of Innermost Div at Screen Top</button>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="a">a
  <div id="aa">aa
    <div id="aaa">aaa</div>
    <div id="aab">aab
      <div id="aaba">aaba</div>
      <div id="aabb">aabb</div>
      <div id="aabc">aabc</div>
    </div>
    <div id="aac">aac</div>
  </div>
  <div id="ab">ab
    <div id="aba">aba</div>
    <div id="abb">abb</div>
    <div id="abc">abc</div>
  </div>
  <div id="ac">ac
    <div id="aca">aca</div>
    <div id="acb">acb</div>
    <div id="acc">acc</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="b">b
  <div id="ba">ba
    <div id="baa">baa</div>
    <div id="bab">bab</div>
    <div id="bac">bac</div>
  </div>
  <div id="bb">bb
    <div id="bba">bba</div>
    <div id="bbb">bbb</div>
    <div id="bbc">bbc</div>
  </div>
  <div id="bc">bc
    <div id="bca">bca</div>
    <div id="bcb">bcb</div>
    <div id="bcc">bcc</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="c">c
  <div id="ca">ca
    <div id="caa">caa</div>
    <div id="cab">cab</div>
    <div id="cac">cac</div>
  </div>
  <div id="cb">cb
    <div id="cba">cba</div>
    <div id="cbb">cbb</div>
    <div id="cbc">cbc</div>
  </div>
  <div id="cc">cc
    <div id="cca">cca</div>
    <div id="ccb">ccb</div>
    <div id="ccc">ccc</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is a non-jQuery version of the same thing:

```js
var doc = document;
doc.getElementById("check").onclick = function() {
  var topElem = doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];     // start at the outermost, i.e. the body
  var checkChildDivs = function() {                      // define the recursive checking function
    var children = topElem.childNodes;                   // get all child nodes
    if (children.length > 0) {                           // if there are any child nodes
      [].forEach.call(children, function(elem, index, arr) { // check each of them
        if (elem.toString() === "[object HTMLDivElement]" && elem.id !== "info") {
                                                         // only use divs that do not have id "info"
          var posns = getPosns(elem);                    // get their top and bottom posns
                                                         //   relative to the top of the screen
          if ((posns.top <= 0) && (posns.bottom >= 0)) { // if the div overlaps the screen top
            topElem = elem;                              // make this the new innermost div
            checkChildDivs();                            // check any deeper child divs
            return false;                                // no need to check any lower sibling divs
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
  checkChildDivs();                                      // initiate the checking recursion
  doc.getElementById("info").innerHTML = (topElem.id || "none, i.e. body");
                                                         // report the innermost top div id
};

function getPosns(elem) {
  var top = elem.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset - doc.documentElement.clientTop;
                                   // get the top of the div relative to the document
  var hgt = elem.offsetHeight;     // get the height of the element
  var wst = window.scrollY;        // get the height of window hidden above the top of the screen
  return {                         // return the top and bottom distances of the element
    top: (top - wst),              // relative to the top of the screen
    bottom: (top - wst + hgt)
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
div {
  border: solid black 2px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  background-color: magenta;
}
div > div {
  background-color: red;
}
div > div > div {
  background-color: orange;
}
div >div > div > div {
  background-color: yellow;
}
button#check {
  position: fixed;
  height: 2em;
}
div#info {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  border-width: 1px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  top: 3em;
  left: -0.2em;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 15em;
}
```

```html
<button id="check">Determine Id of Innermost Div at Screen Top</button>
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="a">a
  <div id="aa">aa
    <div id="aaa">aaa</div>
    <div id="aab">aab
      <div id="aaba">aaba</div>
      <div id="aabb">aabb</div>
      <div id="aabc">aabc</div>
    </div>
    <div id="aac">aac</div>
  </div>
  <div id="ab">ab
    <div id="aba">aba</div>
    <div id="abb">abb</div>
    <div id="abc">abc</div>
  </div>
  <div id="ac">ac
    <div id="aca">aca</div>
    <div id="acb">acb</div>
    <div id="acc">acc</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="b">b
  <div id="ba">ba
    <div id="baa">baa</div>
    <div id="bab">bab</div>
    <div id="bac">bac</div>
  </div>
  <div id="bb">bb
    <div id="bba">bba</div>
    <div id="bbb">bbb</div>
    <div id="bbc">bbc</div>
  </div>
  <div id="bc">bc
    <div id="bca">bca</div>
    <div id="bcb">bcb</div>
    <div id="bcc">bcc</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="c">c
  <div id="ca">ca
    <div id="caa">caa</div>
    <div id="cab">cab</div>
    <div id="cac">cac</div>
  </div>
  <div id="cb">cb
    <div id="cba">cba</div>
    <div id="cbb">cbb</div>
    <div id="cbc">cbc</div>
  </div>
  <div id="cc">cc
    <div id="cca">cca</div>
    <div id="ccb">ccb</div>
    <div id="ccc">ccc</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool. But the only problem is that I wanted to do it in bare JavaScript.

Comment: By the way, how were you able to post this answer to a closed question? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to fix. The jQuery part of this is simply to make finding the parts a little easier, but its not necessary. The 'guts' of the routine is vanilla JavaScript. I'll see if I can remove the jQuery. Otherwise, is this what you were looking for? With respect to posting in a closed question...I suspect it's because I've had this window open for a number of hours as I worked on this. Beat the system!

Comment: Your result is exactly what I wanted. I didn't know that SO works like that. Great.

Comment: I just added a version that does not use jQuery. I left both versions in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library : https://github.com/customd/jquery-visible .
Check my snippet for demo

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $visible = null;
    $('section > div').each(function() {
      if (!$visible && $(this).visible(true)) {
        $visible = $(this);
        $(this).addClass('active');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
      }
    });
    $('#answer').html('' + $visible.text());
  });
});
```

```css
#main1,
#main2,
#main3,
#main4 {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
body {
  background: blue;
}
section > div {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
section > div.active {
  background: red;
}
#answer {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://opensource.teamdf.com/visible/jquery.visible.js"></script>
<section id="main1">
  <div style="height:100px;">child 1</div>
</section>
<section id="main2">
  <div style="height:100px;">child 2</div>
</section>
<section id="main3">
  <div style="height:100px;">child 3</div>
</section>
<section id="main4">
  <div style="height:300px;">child 4</div>
  <div style="height:400px;">child 5</div>
</section>
<div id="answer"></div>
```

Comment: I want to do it without loading a library. But thanks for answering.

Comment: hmm. okay :) ill try..